# Camera.PreviewCallback cannot get video frame callback data

Tags: android, android-camera

When I use the camera, I use `Camera.PreviewCallback` to get the callback frame data. It works well at the beginning without any problems, but at a certain time the `onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)` function no longer calls back the video frame data. You can check the log See this error occurs within this time:

> M6441D9  08-23 00:41:48.143   363 27947 I Cam3OEMIf: 8244, Callback_PreviewFree: mPreviewHeapNum 0 sum 8
> M6441DA  08-23 00:41:48.143   363 27947 E cmr_oem : 495, camera_free: hal_err error param mem_type=0x34,oem_handle=0xa9657800,fd=0xa346ab60,vir_addr=0x0
> M6441DB  08-23 00:41:48.143   363 27947 D RefBase : RefBase: Explicit destruction, weak count = 0 (in 0xa965bcc0)
> M6441DC  08-23 00:41:48.143   363 27947 W RefBase : CallStack::getCurrentInternal not linked, returning null
> M6441DD  08-23 00:41:48.143   363 27947 W RefBase : CallStack::logStackInternal not linked
> M6441DE  08-23 00:41:48.143   363 27947 D RefBase : RefBase: Explicit destruction, weak count = 0 (in 0xa965bd00)
> M6441DF  08-23 00:41:48.143   363 27947 W RefBase : CallStack::getCurrentInternal not linked, returning null
> M6441E0  08-23 00:41:48.143   363 27947 W RefBase : CallStack::logStackInternal not linked
> M6441E1  08-23 00:41:48.143   363 27947 D RefBase : RefBase: Explicit destruction, weak count = 0 (in 0xa965bd40)
> M6441E2  08-23 00:41:48.143   363 27947 W RefBase : CallStack::getCurrentInternal not linked, returning null
> M6441E3  08-23 00:41:48.143   363 27947 W RefBase : CallStack::logStackInternal not linked
> M6441E4  08-23 00:41:48.143   363   664 I Cam3OEMIf: 3509, stopPreviewInternal: X Time:142 ms camera id 0
> M6441E5  08-23 00:41:48.143   363   664 I Cam3OEMIf: 888, stop: channel_type = 2, frame_number = 54
> M6441E6  08-23 00:41:48.143   363   664 W Cam3OEMIf: 3579, cancelPictureInternal: not taking a picture (state SPRD_IDLE)
> M6441E7  08-23 00:41:48.143   363   664 W Cam3Channel: 274, channelClearAllQBuff: channel has no valied stream
> M6441E8  08-23 00:41:48.144   439 27971 D Camera3-Device: processCaptureResult: ANDROID_SPRD_EIS_CROP is null
> M6441E9  08-23 00:41:48.144   439 27971 D Camera3-Device: processCaptureResult: ANDROID_SPRD_EIS_CROP is null
> M6441EA  08-23 00:41:48.145   439 27971 D Camera3-Device: processCaptureResult: ANDROID_SPRD_EIS_CROP is null
> M6441EB  08-23 00:41:48.145   439 27971 D Camera3-Device: processCaptureResult: ANDROID_SPRD_EIS_CROP is null
> M6441EC  08-23 00:41:48.146   363   664 I Cam3HWI : 1103, flushRequest: :hal3: X
> M6441ED  08-23 00:41:48.146   363   664 E CamDevSession@3.2-impl: processOneCaptureRequest: HAL process_capture_request call failed!
> M6441EE  08-23 00:41:48.146   363 27930 I cmr_sensor: 851, cmr_sns_thread_proc: evt 524548
> M6441EF  08-23 00:41:48.146   439 27971 E Camera3-Device: Camera 0: sendRequestsBatch: RequestThread: Unable to submit capture request 54 to HAL device: Function not implemented (-38)
> M6441F0  08-23 00:41:48.146   439 27971 E Camera2Client: notifyError: Error condition 1 reported by HAL, requestId -1
> M6441F1  08-23 00:41:48.146   363 27930 I cmr_sensor: 1256, cmr_sns_ioctl: cmd = 45, arg = 0xbe9fd32c.
> M6441F2  08-23 00:41:48.147   363 27930 I sharkle_gc2053: 563, gc2053_drv_access_val: sensor gc2053: param_ptr->type=13
> M6441F3  08-23 00:41:48.147   363   363 I Cam3OEMIf: 888, stop: channel_type = 1, frame_number = 54
> M6441F4  08-23 00:41:48.147   363   363 I Cam3OEMIf: 3447, stopPreviewInternal: E mCameraId=0
> M6441F5  08-23 00:41:48.147   363   363 I Cam3OEMIf: 2565, isPreviewIdle: SPRD_IDLE
> M6441F6  08-23 00:41:48.147   363   363 I Cam3OEMIf: 3509, stopPreviewInternal: X Time:-4710836733499 ms camera id 0
> M6441F7  08-23 00:41:48.147   363   363 I Cam3OEMIf: 888, stop: channel_type = 2, frame_number = 54
> M6441F8  08-23 00:41:48.147   363   363 W Cam3OEMIf: 3579, cancelPictureInternal: not taking a picture (state SPRD_IDLE)
> M6441F9  08-23 00:41:48.147   363   363 I Cam3HWI : 2042, flush: :hal3: clear all buffers
> M6441FA  08-23 00:41:48.147   363   363 W Cam3Channel: 274, channelClearAllQBuff: channel has no valied stream
> M6441FB  08-23 00:41:48.147   363   363 W Cam3Channel: 274, channelClearAllQBuff: channel has no valied stream
> M6441FC  08-23 00:41:48.148   363   363 W Cam3Channel: 274, channelClearAllQBuff: channel has no valied stream
> M6441FD  08-23 00:41:48.148   363   363 W Cam3Channel: 274, channelClearAllQBuff: channel has no valied stream
> M6441FE  08-23 00:41:48.148   363   363 I Cam3HWI : 2096, flush: :hal3: X

What is the possible reason for this error, and is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.